# Filter pandas dataframe inside of function and return filtered dataframe

Tags: python, function, class, global, local

I have a class with online and offline data and i want to use a function which can filter the data according to existing columns.
The following code works:

```
class Exp:
def __init__(self):
    d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3' : [5,6]}
    d2 = {'col1': [7, 8], 'col2': [9, 10], 'col3' : [11,12]}
    
    self.online = pd.DataFrame(d)
    self.offline = pd.DataFrame(d2)



def filter_cols(self, typ, cols):

    if typ == "on":
        self.online = self.online.filter(items= cols)
    if typ == "off":
        self.offline = self.offline.filter(items = cols)


print("before")
a = Exp()
print(a.online)
a.filter_cols("on", cols = ['col1', 'col2'])
print("after")
print(a.online)
```

outcome:

```
    before
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
after
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

But i want to make my function more genereic so that i dont have to specify the if and else statements in the function. So basically i want something like the following to work

```
class Exp:
.
.
.

    def filter_cols(self, data, cols):

        data.filter(items= cols)
        


print("before")
a = Exp()
print(a.online)
a.filter_cols(a.online, cols = ['col1', 'col2'])
print("after")
print(a.online)
```

But the outcome remains the same:

```
before
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
after
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
```

Comment: why exactly do you need 2 dataframes?

Comment: I have a big class with many different types of data, ("online", "offline" and so an..) and every data type is a dataframe with different columns. In my class i just want to filter according to columns no matter what datatype is given to the function

Comment: could you instead make a class, where it would only have one dataframe, and then have multiple instances of this class?

Comment: well that might also be a more generic solution, maybe i will do that instead tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setattr` and `getattr` like this:

```
    def filter_cols(self, typ, cols):
        setattr(self, typ + 'line', getattr(self, typ + 'line').filter(items= cols))
```

Full code:

```
class Exp:
    def __init__(self):
        d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'col3' : [5,6]}
        d2 = {'col1': [7, 8], 'col2': [9, 10], 'col3' : [11,12]}
        
        self.online = pd.DataFrame(d)
        self.offline = pd.DataFrame(d2)



    def filter_cols(self, typ, cols):
        setattr(self, typ + 'line', getattr(self, typ + 'line').filter(items= cols))


print("before")
a = Exp()
print(a.online)
a.filter_cols("on", cols = ['col1', 'col2'])
print("after")
```

Output:

```
before
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     2     4     6
after
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1     2     4
```

Comment: That works and i was not aware of setattr and getattr yet. But what if there are more than online and offline which dont end on 'line'. Is there a generic way to just give the function the dataframe like that a.filter_cols(a.online, cols = ['col1', 'col2']) and the function can change the right data?

Comment: @coderxXx That's unfortunately impossible with python, since `a.online` would reference to the dataframe object not the attrbute.

Comment: @coderxXx Read about setattr and getattr [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

Comment: Hey thanks man thats very helpful, i just read the docs but i dont understand the getattr into the setattr line. COuld you please explain this line of code?

Comment: @coderxXx Read [thus](https://medium.com/@pranaygore/using-getattr-setattr-delattr-hasattr-in-python-6d79c6f9fda3) then.